# What does the python interactive console output?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, python-interactive

When I `import` the `datetime` module for example, and create a `datetime.datetime` object, thus that this `datetime.datetime` object is the value of the expression, it returns

```
datetime.datetime(*values inserted*)
```

But this is not the `_str__()` return value of `datetime.datetime`.

How is the output of the interactive console defined to behave?
Is there a specification or comprehensible explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It shows the value of `__repr__()`.